# Getting a rank back when querying a rank int

Tags: php, mysql, join

Im trying to get a Rank Name back from my `'us_army_ranks'` field in my mysql database via the members `'rank'` field in the same database.

So far im trying to do it like this.

```
SELECT 'members'.'rank', 'us_army_ranks'.'id' FROM members LEFT JOIN 'us_army_ranks' ON 'members'.'rank'='us_army_ranks'.'rank'
```

Im stuck and cant really get it to work. Im using `$id=$_GET['id'];` also that would make it look like this.

```
SELECT 'members'.'rank', 'us_army_ranks'.'id' FROM members WHERE id='$id' LEFT JOIN 'us_army_ranks' ON 'members'.'rank'='us_army_ranks'.'rank'
```

I get a:

> "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in ranks.php on line 13" return but there is not any
>   data missing.

Comment: I would hope the US Army is not using **`mysql_*()`** functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in using single quotes `'` instead of a backquote `` ` `` around your table and field names.

As they are not keywords (any of them) you do not need to use those quotes around the table and field names at all.

Do:

```
SELECT members.rank, us_army_ranks.id 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN us_army_ranks ON members.rank=us_army_ranks.rank
WHERE members.id='$id'
```

because your query as it was was errorneous, the `mysql_query` function didn't return a resource but a boolean `FALSE` as to notify you the query was wrong and failed to execute.

Comment: I see about the backquote issue, thanks.
But this way still returns a "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/ascmilsi/public_html/ranks.php on line 18"

Comment: Aha! my bad. you have an `id` field in both the tables. the post above is now updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try without the single quotes:

```
SELECT members.rank, us_army_rank.id
FROM members
LEFT JOIN us_army_ranks
ON members.rank = us_army_ranks.rank
WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: Returns me "Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous" when queried in phpmysql. I change $id to 1 just for testing.

Comment: Try wrapping the $id in single quotes